# Remove Drop Shadow from User Form

Tags: excel, userform, dropshadow

Excel 2007
Standard UserForm

How can you remove the drop shadow around the outer edge of the form ?

I am already using an API call to hide the CAPTION BAR.

Comment: I believe this is OS GUI related, not Excel/Userform.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. The code is too long to post so here is the link.  https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/transparent-userform-background-with-vba/